# Connect to a database in Silex

Tags: php, database, silex

i have

```
    $app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
    'db.options' => array(
        'dbname' => 'dbname',
        'user' => 'user',
        'password' => '',
        'host' => 'host',
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql'
    ),
));
```

which is correct, i can connect to the database within PHPStorm directly with the same credentials inserted in this register. But when i

```
echo '<pre>' . var_export($app['db'], true) . '</pre>';
```

i get:

[image: https://gyazo.com/7b9a106c1c44e012ff20bd34b698303c]

I don't understand why it's not saying isConnected = true because the credentials are correct.

EDIT:
 Query attempt based on silex docs example
[image]

This results in the same "Whoops, looks like something went wrong" error.

Comment: It may just simply defer connecting until the first query. Did you try doing a simple select?

Comment: @Maerlyn i did indeed, to no avail unfortunately, see the added select within the question.

Comment: `Whoops, looks like something went wrong` error is just for your site's users. **You** should read your errors in the error log of your web-server. They contain much more details and you can understand what is wrong.

Comment: [Silex comes with a default error handler that displays a detailed error message with the stack trace when debug is true, and a simple error message otherwise.](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/usage.html#error-handlers).

Comment: @djxak Thanks it's helped me isolate the problem, says "Error PDOException: could not find driver in ...\blah\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:43 Stack trace: #0", now to figure out how to fix it :D

Comment: @djxak Just used my ubuntu VM to test it with php, php-mysql re-installed as it's easier to apt-get and my actual server is a linux based one. Works fine, thank you.